# Mixing MLE and Hypothesis Testing

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, maximum-likelihood, multiple-comparisons, aic

In my field of biology, we have spatial data with known distances, so we know a general formula for our error structure that we can use in a generalized least squares context, it is
$$
(1-\lambda)\mathbb{I}_n + \lambda \Sigma_{n}.
$$
However, the current approach is to fit the value of $\lambda$ by maximum likelihood, whichever combination of regression (e.g. $\beta_0$, $\beta_1$) and $\lambda$ gives the MLE of our data, we choose that as our optimal regression.  Then at this location we do a conditional hypothesis test, conditional on our value of $\lambda$, that $\beta_1$ is non-zero, i.e., that there is a relationship between our independent and dependent variable, that they have a significant covariance.  This is easy to do with the standard
$$
t(d.f.=n-2)=\beta_1/V_{11}
$$
test statistic formula.  From a biological perspective, I'm not sure this makes sense, because before we fit $\lambda$, our "prior" is essentially that lambda was sampled from a uniform distribution, and how do we know it isn't possible there is not another lambda value that explains our dependent variable's distribution slightly worse, but with absolutely no covariance.  If such a $\lambda$ existed, I'd argue it shows our hypothesis test showing significance isn't to be trusted.  But on the other hand, if all of the $\lambda$s which give no significant covariance explain the data much worse, then I'd say, "well, we want to explain the data well and give it a high likelihood, so if the only way to do that is with covariance, then great!"

So I've been trying to compare the likelihoods of different models, such as an intercept model, and compare the likelihoods with AICc.  But this seems to be even less reliable in some cases.  Now I'm thinking the original sin was combining hypothesis testing with MLE, but I really have no idea about any of this.  All I know is it seems premature to attribute spatial structure in Y to one combination of error and covariance instead of another combination of error and no covariance.

Q1) Can MLE and hypothesis testing be reliably mixed? Why or why not?

Q2) Any specific advice for my situation?  The biggest problem I'm facing now is that for small sample sizes (e.g. 6 points), all values of $\lambda$ give a significant covariance (where the null is rejected), but also, all the AICc values favor the intercept model (the null).  Which is obviously non-sensical, right?